# How to set multiple outlinePaint to a renderer in jfreechart (I'm using barchart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm new here, well I have a question.
I have this barchart and I need it  to be fill with just one color (each bar), but also, to make a diference I need the outline of each bar to be in a diferent color (red or green)
my method recieve the dataset1 and 2, also the same data inside arrays. Well, I'm comparing my arrays and then I set the color to green or red. 
But, here is the problem, the renderer takes the last value of my serie.
Here's my code:

```
public void crearChartSemanal(DefaultCategoryDataset dataPresupuestos, DefaultCategoryDataset dataGastos, Color[] colores, Color[] coloresBlancos, String tipo, JPanel panel,double[]g,double[]p) {
        Paint coloPaint[] = new Paint[colores.length];
        Paint colorBordes[] = new Paint[coloresBlancos.length];

        coloPaint = coloresBlancos;
        colorBordes = colores;
        final CategoryItemRenderer rendererP = new CustomRenderer(
                coloPaint);


        Paint outline = Color.BLACK;
//        Paint orilla=new Paint(Color.CYAN);

        System.out.println("count "+g.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
            if (g[i] > p[i]) {
//                outline = Color.YELLOW;
                 rendererP.setSeriesOutlinePaint(i,Color.green); 
                 System.out.println("pase al rojo");
            } else if (g[i]<=p[i]){
                //outline = Color.RED;
                rendererP.setSeriesOutlinePaint(i,Color.red); //the renderer takes this value at the end
                System.out.println("njhbñ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Estoy aquí");
        //    renderer.setLabelGenerator(generator);
        rendererP.setItemLabelsVisible(true);       
        final CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot();

        plot.setDataset(dataGastos);
//        plot.setOutlinePaint(null);
```

....
(Also, I'm sorry about my english, hope you understand)

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass the [BarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html) class you can override `getItemOutlinePaint()` and return any color you want for an item's outline.

Comment: Thank you, for now I've figured out the way to make it look good without the outline, but I'm gonna try what you said :)